# How drop duplicate rows based on a time delta whilst keep the latest occurrence of that record?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, duplicates

I have a table in the form:

| ID | DATE_ENCOUNTER | LOAD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 151336 | 2017-08-22 | 40 |
| 151336 | 2017-08-23 | 40 |
| 151336 | 2017-08-24 | 40 |
| 151336 | 2017-08-25 | 40 |
| 151336 | 2017-09-05 | 50 |
| 151336 | 2017-09-06 | 50 |
| 151336 | 2017-10-16 | 51 |
| 151336 | 2017-10-17 | 51 |
| 151336 | 2017-10-18 | 51 |
| 151336 | 2017-10-30 | 50 |
| 151336 | 2017-10-31 | 50 |
| 151336 | 2017-11-01 | 50 |
| 151336 | 2017-12-13 | 62 |
| 151336 | 2018-01-03 | 65 |
| 151336 | 2018-02-09 | 60 |

Although the dates are not the same, some records are duplicates (just within a 4 day delta).How do I drop duplicates (earliest records) in a dataframe if the timestamps/dates are close (within 4 day delta) but not identical. The result should present a table like below:

| ID | DATE_ENCOUNTER | LOAD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 151336 | 2017-08-25 | 40 |
| 151336 | 2017-09-06 | 50 |
| 151336 | 2017-10-18 | 51 |
| 151336 | 2017-11-01 | 50 |
| 151336 | 2017-12-13 | 62 |
| 151336 | 2018-01-03 | 65 |
| 151336 | 2018-02-09 | 60 |

I have tried:

```
m = df.groupby('ID').DATE_ENCOUNTER.apply(lambda x: x.diff().dt.days < 4)
m2 = df.ID.duplicated(keep=false) & (m | m.shift(-1))
df_dedup2 = df[~m2]
```

Here is some code to generate the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
details = {
    'ID':[151336,151336,151336,151336,151336,151336,151336,151336,151336,151336,151336,151336,151336,151336,151336],
    'DATE_ENCOUNTER':['2017-08-22','2017-08-23','2017-08-24','2017-08-25','2017-09-05','2017-09-06','2017-10-16','2017-10-17','2017-10-18','2017-10-30','2017-10-31','2017-11-01','2017-12-13','2018-01-03','2018-02-09'],
    'LOAD':[40,40,40,40,50,50,51,51,51,50,50,50,62,65,60]
}
df=pd.DataFrame(details)
```

Note there are more fields and more IDs.

Comment: Why is "2017-10-17" kept?

Comment: Agree, seems like `2017-10-17` which is only 1 day difference from subsequent `2017-10-18` should not be kept

Comment: @Mazil_tov998 does your remove duplicates need to include the column LOAD as well? I mean if the column LOAD was 30 instead of 40 for the first date, would you remove it as the date is within 4 days of the following ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df[(df.groupby('ID')
      ['DATE_ENCOUNTER']
      .diff(-1).dt.days.mul(-1) # calculate the difference
      .fillna(float('inf'))     # make sure last row is kept
      .ge(4)                    # select diff >= 4
   )]
```

output:

```
        ID DATE_ENCOUNTER  LOAD
3   151336     2017-08-25    40
5   151336     2017-09-06    50
8   151336     2017-10-18    51
11  151336     2017-11-01    50
12  151336     2017-12-13    62
13  151336     2018-01-03    65
14  151336     2018-02-09    60
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
#Convert to datetime format if not already in datetime
#df['DATE_ENCOUNTER'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_ENCOUNTER'])

#Sort DATE_ENCOUNTER within the same ID if not already in this sequence
#df = df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'DATE_ENCOUNTER'])
```

```
# reuse your code of mask `m`
m = df.groupby('ID').DATE_ENCOUNTER.apply(lambda x: x.diff().dt.days < 4)

# set grouping of consecutive entries within 4 days difference within the same `ID` 
g = (~m).groupby(df['ID']).cumsum()

# pick the last entry in each group
df.groupby(['ID', g], as_index=False).last()
```

**Result:**

```
       ID DATE_ENCOUNTER  LOAD
0  151336     2017-08-25    40
1  151336     2017-09-06    50
2  151336     2017-10-18    51
3  151336     2017-11-01    50
4  151336     2017-12-13    62
5  151336     2018-01-03    65
6  151336     2018-02-09    60
```